# Passing pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
      main()
        {
            char** names = NULL;
            int numStudents = 0;
            AddStudent(&names,"Bob", NumStudents);
            printf("%s", names[0]);
        }
```

A function that add a student to the array

```
void AddStudent(char*** names, char* name, int numStudents) 
        {
        numStudents++;
        *names = (char**)realloc(*names, sizeof(char*)*numStudents);
        if (*names == NULL) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        char** arr = *names;
        AddStringToArray(arr, name, numStudents);
    }
    void AddStringToArray(char** arr, char* str, int index)
    {
        arr[index-1] = malloc(strlen(str));
        if (arr[index-1] == NULL) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(arr[index-1], str);
    }
```

I tried this and got this comment-

```
Error reading characters of string
```

when I try to print in the main function

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Being a "three star programmer" in C is not a compliment.

Comment: How should I write this code without using 3 stars and sending the address of the array to the function?

Comment: Twinkle, twinkle, little star, now I know just what you are. C's most misused without question, stuck in there for indirection.

Comment: Can you explain me why please? it still doesn't work without the third star.. If I print  printf("%s", names[0]); it sends an error.

Comment: Hi, please post a minimal compilable example with a description of what the code should do, as suggested by Marged http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Do you allocate some memory for names anywhere in your code? Any chance to know what (and how) InsertOrUpdate() does?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your first code block references `InsertOrUpdate()` but the second code block defines `AddName()` — that's a little confusing. The compiler should be giving you warnings if not errors when you compile `AddName()`; the first argument to `strcpy()` should be a `char *` but you are passing a `char **` (speaking casually, the subscript removes one of the three stars).  You really need to provide more code.  As others noted, triple-star is hard to understand for anyone — avoid it if you can. But we can't help much with so little code.

Comment: yes, *names = (char**)realloc(*names, sizeof(char*));

Comment: @rotemhas This is completely wrong: `names = (char*)realloc(names, sizeof(char));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a simple starting point for AddStringToArray:**

1. Pass an array of strings, so a `char**`.
2. Pass the index of where to add the new `char*`.
3. Be sure the index you pass is in bounds of the array to ensure enough space is allocated.

**The calling code:**

```
char* names[3];
size_t namesCapacity = 3;
AddStringToArray(names, "Bob", 0, namesCapacity);
AddStringToArray(names, "Sue", 1, namesCapacity);
AddStringToArray(names, "Pete", 2, namesCapacity);
```

**AddStringToArray defined:**

```
void AddStringToArray(char** arr, char* str, size_t index, size_t arrCapacity) {
    if (index >= namesCapacity) 
        printf("Error, out of bounds\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    arr[index] = malloc(strlen(str));
    if (arr[index] == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(arr[index], str);
}
```

---

**In reponse to comment:**

If you cannot track size of the array, we can create another function to reallocate if necessary.

```
void AddOrUpdate(char*** arrPtr, char* str, size_t index)
{
    *arrPtr = realloc(*arrPtr, index+1);
    if(*arrPtr == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char** arr = *arrPtr;
    AddStringToArray(arr, str, index, index+1);
}
```

**Then call it like this:**

```
char** names = NULL;
AddOrUpdate(&names, "Bob", 0);
AddOrUpdate(&names, "Sue", 1);
AddOrUpdate(&names, "Pete", 2);
```

**Note:** Make sure you're always adding to the end of the array. If you add to the middle, this implementation will realloc to that point and you'll lose everything after that index.

Further, if you simply want to add the string to the end of the array, you'll have to use a terminating NULL within the bounds of your array. Then when you want to add something, iterate to it from the beginning of the array, and pass that as the index to `AddOrUpdate`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I don't know the size of names and I want to send names to a function. When I send it I want it to be back to the main function updated. What should I do?

Comment: You should keep track of your array's size.

Comment: Check out the updated answer

Comment: Thank you. I updated my problem.

Comment: Aw okay works! Thank you!